# Is Salesforce adding decimals wrongly?

Tags: apex, custom-object, formula-field, currency

Problem Description: Having weird decimals calculation

Field 1(formula(Currency)): 0.53

Field 2(formula(Currency)): 5.27

Formula field Total = field 1 + field 2

Total = 0.53 + 5.27

```
Expected: Total should be 5.80

Actual output: Total is 5.79
```

Why this weird behavior?. It should result in 5.80 but it is resulting 5.79.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a case of the precision of fields only being enforced at the UI level? See [Number Type, Decimal Points Confusion](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/136581/number-type-decimal-points-confusion)

You could try doing a SOQL query on your data to confirm e.g. the underlying data could be like this:

```
0.526 + 5.266 = 5.792
```

**Edit**

I'm pretty sure that the above is the root cause, so I went through all the working. I created two Currency fields called `C1__c` and `C2__c`, set them to `0.526` and `5.266` respectively. I then created two formula fields `CF1__c` and `CF2__c`. These just read the values from `C1__c` and `C2__c`, but they are configured to 2 decimal places:

[image]

And finally, I made a field CT__c which is a formula summing up

```
CF1__c + CF2__c
```

Here's the result of querying that record:

[image]

Which matches your experience. When SF combines formulas, it doesn't take the result of, say `CF1__c`, and plug that value into the other formula `CT__c`. It combines all the formulas into one big formula first, then evaluates the result. So, if you've declared the precision declaratively, that actually gets missed from the compound formula.

If you want to fix it, you can add rounding into your formula. In my example, I can change the definition of `CF1__c` to:

```
ROUND(C1__c, 2)
```

If I do that for `CF1__c` and `CF2__c`, then the result is `5.8`.

Comment: Nope. In the backend it is 0.53 only. Added SOQL result image for reference.

Comment: Crazy... can you share the actual formulas?

Comment: `Total_Amount__c = Tax_Amount__c + Amount__c`  This is straightforward in formula field

Comment: But the tax amount and amount are formulas, too? How are they defined?

Comment: Yes those fields also formula fields. But I don't think we need to look back those since we have exact values in the UI and backend. Because, If there are any decimal points mismatch, we can see in the query result.

Comment: It is important, please read my revised answer.

Comment: @mohammedazarudeen did this resolve your problems in the end? It took me some time to put together all the extra information that I added to my answer and it would be nice to know whether or not it explained what was going on in you org.